# dart's http request in future function returns null

Tags: dart, async-await

I am trying to get data from the website

```
void main() async {
  var resp = await http.get(
    Uri.parse('https://m.example.com/example'),
    headers: {
      'User-Agent':
          'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_4_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148'
    },
  );
  print(resp.body);
}
```

But when I wrap this code into a function, the resp returns null

```
Future getLiveHtml(String url) async {
  var resp = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(url),
    headers: {
      'User-Agent':
          'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_4_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148'
    },
  );
  return resp.body;
}
```

how to fix it?

Comment: Please show the code that calls your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the type you return in method `Future<String>` description like that:

```dart
library shfl;

import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

static Future<String> getLiveHtml(String url) async {
  var resp = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(url),
    headers: {
      'User-Agent':
          'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_4_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148'
    },
  );
  return resp.body;
}
```

and then call it in `async` function with `await` statement like that:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

import 'package:shfl/shfl.dart';

void main() {
  test('prints html from google', () async {
    var rez = await Stuff.getLiveHtml("https://google.com/");
    print(rez);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what version of the `http` package are you using for your project?